# How do I get the identity from a non authorized route

Tags: asp.net-core

Quick question:  In ASP.NET 5 (vNext) how do I get the HttpContext.User to load from the Bearer token embeded in the Authroization header on the request.

It appears if I add the [Authorize("Bearer")] attribute, then the HttpContext.User is populated.  How do I get it to populate without actually requiring authorization on the route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When configuring JwBearerAuthentication, you need to switch on AutomaticAuthentication:

```
app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(options =>
{
    // snipped all other config
    options.AutomaticAuthentication = true;
});
```

With this, the User on the context will be populated on all end-points if they provide a token, and users without a token can still access.

Note that this exact syntax will change in ASP.NET 5 1.0.0-rc1 - see [this breaking change announcement](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/83).